# Fail to read/write hdfs when elasticsearch-spark-20 in classpath

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

Getting the following error when spark job writes data to hdfs
This specific job doesn't read/write to elastic, but the jar includes it in the classpath dependencies (fat jar)

I'm using:
scala 2.11.8
spark: 2.1.0
elastic: elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11 (v5.6.7)

How this can be fixed?

```
User class threw exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource15 not found
   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource15 not found
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:550)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:424)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
```

Here is a snippet from my pom dependencies:

```
 <properties>
    <spark.version>2.1.2</spark.version>
    <elasticsearch.version>5.6.7</elasticsearch.version>
    <scala.major.version>2.11</scala.major.version>
    <scala.minor.version>8</scala.minor.version>
    <lz4.version>1.3.0</lz4.version>
    <jackson.version>2.8.5</jackson.version>
</properties>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_${scala.major.version} </artifactId>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>net.jpountz.lz4</groupId>
        <artifactId>lz4</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- Spark dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-catalyst_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.major.version}.${scala.minor.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_${scala.major.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/923?

Comment: Yep, I've found it. But unfortunately, there was no solution for me. The version I use is correct, and split a jar doesn't help (if a job read from hdfs, and write to hdfs and elastic... )

Comment: Can you please post your pom.xml or whatever you have to show the dependency list?

Comment: it fails on line dfRdd.write.format("csv").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(outputPath)

Comment: The only thing missing now is **how** your constructing your RDD. What API are you using?

Comment: val rdd = hc.table(table).where(whereDates).as[MyObj] ...(after some calculations)  val dfRdd=rdd.toDF

Comment: How were you running the spark job? via `spark-submit`? If so, then you should specify the path to the elasticsearch-spark jar in the `spark-submit` command.